# Sending a letter to Manila/Philippines to be picked up at the post office (Poste Restante)

Tags: philippines, mail, manila

I need to send a letter to a person who is in Manila (Philippines) but she doesn't have a postal address where she can receive the letter. So I would like to send the letter to a post office and then she will be able to pick up the letter from them.

This service is usually known as [Poste Restante](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poste_restante).

Do you know if there is a service like that in Manila?

Answer (score 6):

From the 2010 Rough Guide: Philippines

"Major post offices in Manila and elsewhere have a counter for Poste Restante."

There is also at least one Mail Boxes, Etc. in Manila; no doubt using them would cost more than regular mail. Also, I am not sure if they provide the same services internationally as the ones in the U.S.A. do, so you might not be able to send a letter for onsite pick up there.

Comment: Ok, thanks.. Do you know where I could find more information about that? What I should do exactly to use those services if they are available in Manila's post offices? I was looking at the Philippine Postal Service website (https://www.phlpost.gov.ph/) but I can't find anything..

Comment: If you can communicate via phone or email with your friend in Manila, ask her to go to a post office, preferably one of the bigger ones, and ask about how poste restante works there; she can then email/call you with details to ensure your letter goes to the right particular post office. Other than that, I would dig for a customer service phone or email address. Good luck!

Comment: Also, off topic and at the risk of lots of downvotes, if this friend is someone whom you have never met in person and you are trying to send her money (at her request), please please please reconsider!

Answer (score 2):

She needs check with the post office. Normally were I live. The post office sends you a note to your postal drop to come to the bigger city to get your package or id duty is owed.  Does she have a Philippine postal I.D. card? She is picking up nothing at the post office with out that! That card should have the information needed on it as to how or were to send to her. Your postal I.D. is the number 1 I.D. in the Philippines. So she should know that. And have that I.D.. If not she need get one before picking up any thing from the post office or a postal drop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is a "postal drop"?

Comment: Postal drop. Is the little store at the top of the hill on the main road. The mail stops there & the post person drops it off.  You go there & pick it up. Kind of like small town America were you get a post office box. But No box there they know most in the area. You just stop & pick up your mail. Bills & such. If it looks important the will send a boy down to tell you or a neighbors kid coming home from school will tell you important letter at store.

Answer (score -1):

Your friend should check with a local post office in the Philippines, but as far as I know, most, if not all, countries have this service.  In Canada we call it "General Delivery" in English (still "Poste Restante" in francophone regions), so the name might change.

Some postal services have a fee for this; many (e.g. Canada) don't.  But it would be best to verify this at the destination directly.

Failing this, there are often package/mail services that will accept letters and packages for others, for a fee.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.